# How to compare a comma separated string with a string and replace with the string with comma separated values

Tags: sql-server

I have a column A which contains comma separated values for ex. `"5,6,7"`
and another column B contain `"5"`.

I have to compare column B value with column A value and replace with a certain value. In this case i want to replace `"5,6,7"` with `"8,6,7"`.

Is this possible with  Sql server

Thank you.

Comment: The real solution is fix your design. Never store delimited data in your database.

Comment: If you're storing comma-separated data in a column, you're doing it wrong. This cries out for an additional table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to split up the values, then `REPLACE` and `STRING_AGG` to reaggregate

```sql
SELECT B = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(REPLACE(value, '5', '8'), ',')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(YourTable.A, ',')
)
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface thanks for your response, what i want is not to update in table instead in output i want to just replace it with that string.

Comment: OK just change it to `select`